# Locked server because of IP spoofing

Tags: firewall, docker, ip, spoofing, hetzner

I have hetzner server. Inside this server there is Docker service which inside creates a few containers. Inside this containers I create vpn connections with openvpn. After connection I make some external requests from this tunnels inside containers.

Hetzner locked this server saying that I'm spoofing source IP address. Maybe you had similar issue or you have some ideas where to look at.

Docker containers run with systemd enabled and the following permissions:

```
"CapAdd": [
                "NET_ADMIN",
                "NET_RAW",
                "SYS_ADMIN",
                "ALL"
            ]

"Dns": [
                "8.8.8.8",
                "8.8.4.4"
            ]

"SecurityOpt": [
                "seccomp=unconfined",
                "label=disable"
            ]

"Sysctls": {
                "net.ipv4.ip_forward": "1",
                "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6": "1",
                "net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding": "1",
                "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6": "1",
                "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6": "1"
            }

"Devices": [
                {
                    "PathOnHost": "/dev/net/tun",
                    "PathInContainer": "/dev/net/tun",
                    "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
                }
            ]
```

After systemd init, I just run openvpn connection with my ovpn file and that's all. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> After systemd init, I just run openvpn connection with my ovpn file and that's all. What could be wrong?

You don't do NAT, so you send traffic with a source different from the IP Hetzner has assigned to you. This is caught automatically by their systems and blocked.

Clean up your act and ensure all traffic egress from the assigned IP from Hetzner. Use NAT to rewrite source.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not expert in networking, only software. This gave me some info to speak with chatgpt4 and it suggested me to do this: ` iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`. Could this be correct way?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on the concepts, and not relying on LLM's for system administration. They're kinda known to hallucinate...

Comment: Okay, I understand that reading and understanding is the correct way, but it this a good direction to look in? Because when I looked into iprouting I found this: `MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0` So docker already applied this rule. Maybe you can give me more keywords that I should research and read about?

Comment: Docker by default masquerades yes - but you give your containers net_raw. Additionally it depends on the docker file what networking it uses. In short: You ***need*** to understand the technology you use. You have given us a *small* piece of your configuration, so the answer is general: You need to enable masquerading. For how to do that, you have to understand your technology stack!